# Call PHP from jQuery when browser, or browser tab closes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Below is `jquery` code that displays an alert before closing the tab or browser window:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    if(leave_window == false){
        debugger;
        var i =1;
        i++;
        alert('123'+i);
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }  
});
```

I have a `php` function `sendMail()` that I would like to call from this code block but I am struggling to do so. How can I call my `php` function before the browser closes?

Comment: why would u wanna do that?

Comment: use ajax to make a get or post request.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    if(leave_window == false){
        debugger;
        var i =1;
        i++;


var data = {
    name: $("#form_name").val(),
    email: $("#form_email").val(),
    message: $("#msg_text").val()
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){

    }
});

 alert('123'+i);
        return 'Mail sent Successfully.. Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }  
});
```

in email.php

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['text'];

//send email
    mail("example@gmail.com", "51 Deep comment from" .$email, $message);
}
?>
```

Try this..
I think, it will give u a better solution for ur pblm

Comment: You better remove the email address from your post.